Редактирование элемента RadListBox
Интересует вопрос, можно ли на WPF, как на Winforms, запустить редактирование имени элемента (например ListBox) и после изменения в UI прокинуть новое значение в свойство объекта.
<telerik:RadListBox x:Name="EmpList" Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="50" SelectionMode="Single"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ElectricityMeteringPoints}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEMP, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </telerik:RadListBox>


Если речь про x:Name, то у вас их вовсе не должно быть, ибо WPF - это привязки, а не прямое обращение к контролам.

Не про x:Name. Вот в Winforms можно у ListView на элементе вызвать BeginEdit и отредактировать имя элемента. Можно ли также на WPF реализовать?

При чем тут "имя элемента" я не пойму. BeginEdit - это простое редактирование ячейки. Ключевое тут "ячейки", а если точнее, то такой функционал есть у тех элементов, которые выводят таблицу (DataGrid/ListView), поправьте если не так. В WPF у таблиц также есть редактирование, достаточно привязать к свойству c сеттером (set;). У вас в вопросе ListBox, ну а эти элементы служат по большей части для отображения, а не редактирования.  Если вам нужно редактирование, то измените шаблон объекта, задав там TextBox привязанный к свойству, будет тогда редактирование.

Немного почитал про xaml, остановился на таком варианте. Критика приветствуется :)
UI:


    <telerik:RadListBox Grid.Row="1" 
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ElectricityMeteringPoints}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEMP, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleControl},ConverterParameter=True}"/>
                     <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"
                              BorderThickness="0"
                              Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadListBoxItem}}, Path=Background}"
                              Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleControl},ConverterParameter=False}"/>
                 </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
         </telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadListBox>



конвертер:
public class BoolToVisibleControl : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var isVisible = (bool?) value ?? false;
        if (parameter != null && parameter.ToString() == "True")
            isVisible = !isVisible;

        return isVisible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


работает? отвечает запросу? тестировали?

Да, работает. Сейчас только появился вопрос, как при изменении наименования можно внедрить логику проверки (совпадение с уже существующими элементами и длину строки).
